# Sorting a column with 4 character code

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a small question I need help with.

In my Excell workbook some data and i would like to sort the data in the column. Data in this column is 4 characters long XXXX. First character is always the same ( X ), the second is a number from 0-9, third also a number 0-9 and the fourth a character A-Z. The column should be grouped from the 3rd X ergo the 2nd number and then sorted on the 4th character.

How to do it?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper column to sort by.  For instance, if your data is in column A, put this formula in B1: `=right(A1,2)`. Then drag the formula down.

To sort, select both columns together, and open the sort dialog: [image] Select the helper column to "sort by".

Comment: My man. Worked like a charm! Thanks mate.